# Basic for ELK Stack with Filebeats in windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to ELK Stack and unable to get basic working. Please help.

### Steps Done:

- Started elasticsearch.bat (Started Fine)
- Open http://localhost:9200 in Chrome and got:

  ```
   {
    "name" : "SrfDQVN",
    "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
    "cluster_uuid" : "ZtUOrpL8S8q5gAdh6tCS4g",
    "version" : {
    "number" : "6.3.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "eb782d0",
    "build_date" : "2018-06-29T21:59:26.107521Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.3.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
   }
  ```
- Logstash sample.conf file in logstash dir

-sample.conf

```
    input {
  beats {
    type => beats
    port => 5044
    host => "localhost"
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_IS08601:timestamp_string}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:line}"]
    }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp_string" , "IS08601" ]
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [message, timestamp_string]
  }
}

output {

  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }

}
```

- logstash.yml

  ```
  http.host: "127.0.0.1"
  http.port: 5044
  ```
- Started logstash using command from logstash directory

  ```
  bin\logstash -f sample.conf
  ```
- Here is the last line from the command window after starting logstash

  ```
  [2018-08-01T23:54:00,246][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>5044}
  ```
- Filebeat sample.log file

  ```
  2018-08-01T13:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 1111
  2018-08-01T14:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 2222
  2018-08-01T15:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 3333
  2018-08-01T16:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 4444
  2018-08-01T17:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 5555
  2018-08-01T18:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 6666
  2018-08-01T19:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 7777
  2018-08-01T20:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 8888
  2018-08-01T21:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 9999
  2018-08-01T22:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 11111
  2018-08-01T23:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 22222
  2018-08-01T00:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 33333
  2018-09-01T01:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 44444
  2018-09-01T02:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 55555
  2018-09-01T03:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 66666
  2018-09-01T04:00:00Z I met a traveller from an antique land 77777
  ```
- filebeat.yml file

  ```
  filebeat.prospectors:
   - type: log
   enabled: true
   paths:
     - .\sample.log

  output.logstash:
    hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
  ```
- Running following command to start filebeat through elevated command prompt

  ```
  PS C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64>
   .\filebeat.exe -c .\filebeat.yml -e -v
  ```

I get the following error:

```
        2018-08-02T00:25:22.445+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:492    Home path: [C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64] Config path: [C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64] Data path: [C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\data] Logs path: [C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\logs]
2018-08-02T00:25:22.446+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:499    Beat UUID: eddf3426-d568-4252-8165-ff358472d0a4
2018-08-02T00:25:22.447+0530    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:716    Beat info       {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "C:\\Program Files\\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64", "data": "C:\\Program Files\\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\\data", "home": "C:\\Program Files\\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64", "logs": "C:\\Program Files\\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\\logs"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "eddf3426-d568-4252-8165-ff358472d0a4"}}}
2018-08-02T00:25:22.447+0530    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:725    Build info      {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "45a9a9e1561b6c540e94211ebe03d18abcacae55", "libbeat": "6.3.2", "time": "2018-07-20T04:17:39.000Z", "version": "6.3.2"}}}
2018-08-02T00:25:22.448+0530    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:728    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"windows","arch":"amd64","max_procs":8,"version":"go1.9.4"}}}
2018-08-02T00:25:22.470+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:225    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 6.3.2
2018-08-02T00:25:22.470+0530    INFO    pipeline/module.go:81   Beat name: LP1-AP-51683797
2018-08-02T00:25:22.471+0530    WARN    [cfgwarn]       beater/filebeat.go:61   DEPRECATED: prospectors are deprecated, Use `inputs` instead. Will be removed in version: 7.0.0
2018-08-02T00:25:22.480+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:315    filebeat start running.
2018-08-02T00:25:22.480+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:97   Starting metrics logging every 30s
2018-08-02T00:25:22.481+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:117      Loading registrar data from C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\data\registry
2018-08-02T00:25:22.490+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:124      States Loaded from registrar: 2
2018-08-02T00:25:22.492+0530    WARN    beater/filebeat.go:354  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
2018-08-02T00:25:22.493+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:48   Loading Inputs: 1
2018-08-02T00:25:22.502+0530    INFO    log/input.go:118        Configured paths: [C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\sample.log]
2018-08-02T00:25:22.503+0530    INFO    input/input.go:88       Starting input of type: log; ID: 6142389514979083186
2018-08-02T00:25:22.510+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:82   Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
2018-08-02T00:25:22.511+0530    INFO    log/harvester.go:228    Harvester started for file: C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\sample.log
2018-08-02T00:25:23.532+0530    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2018-08-02T00:25:23.535+0530    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: client is not connected
2018-08-02T00:25:24.535+0530    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:92   Failed to publish events: client is not connected
2018-08-02T00:25:25.370+0530    INFO    beater/filebeat.go:420  Stopping filebeat
2018-08-02T00:25:25.370+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:109  Stopping Crawler
2018-08-02T00:25:25.371+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:119  Stopping 1 inputs
2018-08-02T00:25:25.371+0530    INFO    input/input.go:122      input ticker stopped
2018-08-02T00:25:25.378+0530    INFO    input/input.go:139      Stopping Input: 6142389514979083186
2018-08-02T00:25:25.379+0530    INFO    log/harvester.go:249    Reader was closed: C:\Program Files\filebeat-6.3.2-windows-x86_64\sample.log. Closing.
2018-08-02T00:25:25.379+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:135  Crawler stopped
2018-08-02T00:25:25.380+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:339      Stopping Registrar
2018-08-02T00:25:25.382+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:265      Ending Registrar
2018-08-02T00:25:25.541+0530    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error
2018-08-02T00:25:25.542+0530    ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: client is not connected
2018-08-02T00:25:25.631+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:132  Total non-zero metrics  {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":125,"time":{"ms":125}},"total":{"ticks":156,"time":{"ms":156},"value":156},"user":{"ticks":31,"time":{"ms":31}}},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"b45276ef-6cc2-40b7-8c4d-4e099beedab2","uptime":{"ms":3010}},"memstats":{"gc_next":5746432,"memory_alloc":4250656,"memory_total":6135552,"rss":23027712}},"filebeat":{"events":{"active":15,"added":17,"done":2},"harvester":{"closed":1,"open_files":0,"running":0,"started":1}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"events":{"batches":2,"failed":30,"total":30},"read":{"bytes":6},"type":"logstash","write":{"bytes":778}},"pipeline":{"clients":0,"events":{"active":15,"filtered":2,"published":15,"retry":45,"total":17}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":2,"update":2},"writes":{"success":3,"total":3}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":8}}}}}
2018-08-02T00:25:25.631+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:133  Uptime: 3.2490036s
2018-08-02T00:25:25.633+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:110  Stopping metrics logging.
2018-08-02T00:25:25.634+0530    INFO    instance/beat.go:321    filebeat stopped.
```

Answer (score -1):

try following:

remove this from logstash.yml:

```
http.host: "127.0.0.1"
http.port: 5044
```

Comment: so should it be blank then?